# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Node*&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::atomic<Node*>::__pointer_type {aka Node*}’

Tags: c++11, nonblocking, lock-free

I have the following snippet of code:

```
struct Node {
   int data;
   Node *next;
};

atomic<Node*> head;
atomic<Node*> temp1 = head.load();
..
Node *temp2 = new Node;
//initialise values
head.compare_exchange_strong(temp1, temp2);
```

However, I get the following error:

invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Node*&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::atomic::__pointer_type {aka Node*}’.

I am not getting which reference is constant here. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is that temp1 should be a Node*, not an Atomic,
as cmp/xchg takes two simple type variables.

But I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve.
Surely if you want next to be protected against threading, then it should be declared Atomic inside the struct?

Comment: The first example here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange do not make their next field atomic. I believe this should work.